# Exclude Spring MVC Controller from Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a web application secured with spring security (Spring 3.1.0). Now if a customer wants to register to my service, Spring Security say "No". This makes sense because the user is not yet authorized.

The controller, which gets the register data is a spring mvc controller. I need to exclude this from spring security I think.

I've excluded some urls so far like this:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

Is it possible, to exclude a (Spring MVC)Controller, or is this the wrong way to approach this?

By the way, I also tried to annotate tho at the method:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try permitAll instead?

```
<intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll" />
```